# How to list the published container images in the Google Container Registry in a CLI in image size order

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, size, google-container-registry

Using a CLI, I want to list the images in each repository in a Google Container Registry project but with the following conditions:

- Lists the images with the latest tag only
- Lists the human-readable size of the images
- Lists the name of the images

The closest I've managed to get us through gsutil:

`gsutil du -h gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images`

Resulting in:

```
33.77 MiB   gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:03c1a2387ef6cb30a7428a46821f946d6a2c591a26cb2066891c55b2b6846ae2
1.27 MiB    gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:03c1e7db6bf0140bd5fa34236a35453cb73cef01f6d89b98bc5995ae8ea07aaf
1.32 KiB    gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:03c3c97495d60c68d37d04a7e6c9b3a48bb159ce5dde13d0d81b4e75e2a3f1d4
81.92 KiB   gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:03c5483cb8ac9c9ae498507e15d68d909a11859a8e5238556b7188e0af4d9264
457.43 KiB  gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:03c7f98faa1cfc05264e743e23ca2e118d24c57bfd67d5cb2e2c7a57e8124b6c
7.88 KiB    gs://eu.artifacts.my-registry.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:03c83b13d044844cd3f6b278382e408541f22029acaf55d9e7e5689b8d51eeea
```

But obviously this does not meet most of my criteria.

The information is available through the GUI like so on a per image basis:

[image: google_console]

Any ideas?

I'm open to gsutil, gcloud, docker, anything really which can be installed on a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Cloud UI to accomplish this. There's a column selector right next to the filter bar and it has an option for the image size.

Once the column is displayed, you'll be able to order by size.

Comment: I need to script it, so the Gcloud GUI is useless to me.  Do you know how to get that view through one of the CLI's?

Answer (score 1):

Its seems you have only one outstanding issue with listing container images size after reading your comment at [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9870796/jason)'s answer. So it is not possible to retrieve with gcloud command directly. Here are two work around I tested:

1. You can use gcloud container images [describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/describe) command to see the size of the images. Make sure you use "--log-http" flag with it. Command should be like this:

`$ gcloud container images describe gcr.io/myproject/myimage:tag --log-http`

2. Another way to get the size of the image is using gsutil stat [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat).
   So here's what I did:

a. Upon running below command, I listed all my images from the GCS bucket and saved it to a file called images.txt

```
$ gsutil ls "BUCKET URL" > images.txt
```

b. I ran gcloud stat command like below to read image names from the images.txt file and return size of the images chronologically.

```
$ for x in $(cat images.txt); do `gsutil stat $x | grep Content-Length | awk '{print $2}'`; done
```

You can customize this little script according to your need.

I understand these are not efficient workaround but thats all seems to be an option now. However, GCR just implements the docker container API, so may be you can read this [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#31-containers) to see if you can find/do something of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here just to share a rudimental script which takes the first tag and get the size of the whole layers and write it on a report, it takes ages on 3TB repo but at least i know which repo is big.

```html
echo "REPO,SIZE" > repository-size-report.csv
for REPO in $(gcloud container images list --repository eu.gcr.io/comerge-comerge01-171833 --format="table[no-heading](NAME)") ; do
    for TAGS in $(gcloud container images list-tags $REPO --format="table[no-heading](TAGS)"); do
        TAG=$(echo $TAGS | cut -d, -f1)
        SUM=0

        for SIZE in $(gcloud container images describe $REPO:$TAG --log-http 2>&1 | grep size | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*') ; do
          SUM=$((SUM + SIZE))
        done
        HSUM=$(echo $SUM | numfmt --to iec --format "%8f")
        echo "$REPO:$TAG,$HSUM"
        echo "$REPO:$TAG,$HSUM" >> repository-size-report.csv

    done


done
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command `gcloud container images list` command to accomplish this task; however, you will need to set the appropriate flags to fulfill your use case. You can read more about the command and the flag options [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list#--filter).

Comment: I've already had a go at this and since seeing your comment decided to revisit it.  I've still not been able to get size information from `gcloud container images list`

There's some meta available through `gcloud container images list-tags eu.gcr.io/my-registry/imagename --filter=tags:latest --format=yaml` but still no size information.  Any pointers?  I've been through the page you supplied but I'm still struggling.